# How to connect two docker containers with each other in portainer

Tags: mysql, docker, grafana, zabbix, portainer

I am new to Docker and I am installing Zabbix in Grafana. I need help in making MySQL available in the Grafana I have created Mysql Container it is running and grafana also running I need MySQL in grafana.
But when I use grafana container in the console it shows MySQL is not defined.
[image: Container Images]
I am using it on portainer.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like you should be putting mysql as part of the grafana stack to make it visible.

Comment: yes how i can add this to grafana stack?

Answer (score -1):

Try using docker-compose, it helps you run multiple containers.

Install: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Quickstart: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

More Resources: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=docker-compose